# How can data be passed between Bolts and Javabolts when developing an Apache Storm topology in C#

Tags: c#, azure, apache-storm, azure-hdinsight

we are working on a project where we are using Storm on HDInsight to analyze real-time data. We are using event hubs as input and output and we are having some problems passing the data through the topology. We are currently having one JavaSpout as input handler, one custom Bolt (Bolt1) that is suppose to do some analysis on the data, and one JavaBolt that is suppose to take the analyzed data and send it to the output event hub. Passing data through the JavaSpout and JavaBolts works like a charm, but when we indroduce the custom Bolt the data gets encapsulated or something, its not showing what it should. the output is supposed to show a JSON string, but is shows some random stuff that looks like: [B@6d645e45

Most part of this is code from this tutorial: http://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/documentation/articles/hdinsight-storm-develop-csharp-event-hub-topology/

This is our topology builder:

```
TopologyBuilder topologyBuilder = new TopologyBuilder("EventHubReaderTest");

        int partitionCount = Properties.Settings.Default.EventHubPartitionCount;

        JavaComponentConstructor constructor = JavaComponentConstructor.CreateFromClojureExpr(
            String.Format(@"(com.microsoft.eventhubs.spout.EventHubSpout. (com.microsoft.eventhubs.spout.EventHubSpoutConfig. " +
                @"""{0}"" ""{1}"" ""{2}"" ""{3}"" {4} ""{5}""))",
                Properties.Settings.Default.EventHubPolicyName,
                Properties.Settings.Default.EventHubPolicyKey,
                Properties.Settings.Default.EventHubNamespace,
                Properties.Settings.Default.EventHubNameInput,
                partitionCount,
                ""));

        topologyBuilder.SetJavaSpout(
            "EventHubSpout",
            constructor,
            partitionCount);

        List<string> javaSerializerInfo = new List<string>() { "microsoft.scp.storm.multilang.CustomizedInteropJSONSerializer" };

        topologyBuilder.SetBolt(
            "bolten",
            Bolt1.Get,
            new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
            {
                {Constants.DEFAULT_STREAM_ID, new List<string>(){"Event"}}
            },
            partitionCount).
            DeclareCustomizedJavaSerializer(javaSerializerInfo).
            shuffleGrouping("EventHubSpout");

        JavaComponentConstructor constructorout =
            JavaComponentConstructor.CreateFromClojureExpr(
            String.Format(@"(com.microsoft.eventhubs.bolt.EventHubBolt. (com.microsoft.eventhubs.bolt.EventHubBoltConfig. " +
            @"""{0}"" ""{1}"" ""{2}"" ""{3}"" ""{4}"" {5}))",
            Properties.Settings.Default.EventHubPolicyName,
            Properties.Settings.Default.EventHubPolicyKey,
            Properties.Settings.Default.EventHubNamespace,
            "servicebus.windows.net", //suffix for servicebus fqdn
            Properties.Settings.Default.EventHubNameOutput,
            "true"));

        topologyBuilder.SetJavaBolt(
            "EventHubBolt",
            constructorout,
            partitionCount).
            shuffleGrouping("bolten");

        return topologyBuilder;
```

This is the Bolt that is suppose to do some work

```
public Bolt1(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;

        Dictionary<string, List<Type>> inputSchema = new Dictionary<string, List<Type>>();
        inputSchema.Add("default", new List<Type>() { typeof(string) });

        Dictionary<string, List<Type>> outputSchema = new Dictionary<string, List<Type>>();

        outputSchema.Add("default", new List<Type>() { typeof(string) });

        this.ctx.DeclareComponentSchema(new ComponentStreamSchema(inputSchema, outputSchema));
        this.ctx.DeclareCustomizedDeserializer(new CustomizedInteropJSONDeserializer());

    }

    public static Bolt1 Get(Context ctx, Dictionary<string, Object> parms)
    {
        return new Bolt1(ctx);
    }
    //this is there the magic should happen
    public void Execute(SCPTuple tuple)
    {
        string test = "something";

        //we are currently just trying to emit a string
        ctx.Emit(new Values(test));


    }
```

We hope that we explained the problem good enough, we dont quite grasp how the topology works so its hard to troubleshoot.

**EDIT
We solved it by declaring a deserializer in our topology:**
List javaSerializerInfo = new List() { "microsoft.scp.storm.multilang.CustomizedInteropJSONSerializer" };
            List javaDeserializerInfo = new List() { "microsoft.scp.storm.multilang.CustomizedInteropJSONDeserializer", "java.lang.String" };

```
        topologyBuilder.SetBolt(
            "bolten",
            Bolt1.Get,
            new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
            {
                {Constants.DEFAULT_STREAM_ID, new List<string>(){"Event"}}
            },
            partitionCount).
            DeclareCustomizedJavaSerializer(javaSerializerInfo).
            DeclareCustomizedJavaDeserializer(javaDeserializerInfo).
            shuffleGrouping("EventHubSpout");
```

**And in the custom C# bolt we declared a serializer:**

```
this.ctx.DeclareComponentSchema(new ComponentStreamSchema(inputSchema, outputSchema));
        this.ctx.DeclareCustomizedDeserializer(new CustomizedInteropJSONDeserializer());
        this.ctx.DeclareCustomizedSerializer(new CustomizedInteropJSONSerializer());
```